# how to do get react-phone-input-2 value by using react-hook-form in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am getting TextField value on Submit, but not ReactPhoneInput value, how to get the value using react-hook-form

```
import ReactPhoneInput from "react-phone-input-2"
import {TextField,Button}from "@material-ui/core"

const {register, handleSubmit,formState: { errors }} = useForm()

const getData= (data) => {
   console.log(data.username)
   console.log(data.username);
}
```

form

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(getData)} >

  <TextField {...register("username")} />

   <ReactPhoneInput
      inputExtraProps={{
        name: "phone",
        required: true,
        autoFocus: true
      }}

      country={"in"}
       onlyCountries={["in"]}                     
       countryCodeEditable={false}
        specialLabel={"Player Mobile Number"}
       rules={{ required: true }}
     />
<Button type='submit>Submit</Button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<ReactPhoneInput />` is an external controlled component and therefore you should use RHF's `<Controller />` component here. Check this [section](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingControlledInputs) in the docs for more infos.

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="phone"
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
    <ReactPhoneInput
      {...field}
      inputExtraProps={{
        ref,
        required: true,
        autoFocus: true
      }}
      country={"in"}
      onlyCountries={["in"]}
      countryCodeEditable={false}
      specialLabel={"Player Mobile Number"}
    />
  )}
/>
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - react-phone-input-2]

Comment: how can I validate it,  I want to show error message (I want field should have min 10 and max 10 )

Answer (score 0):

You can still make it work without using `Controller` component, all you have to do is to correctly pass the `onChange` handler from RHF in a correct manner to the `react-phone-input-2`, react-phone-input-2's onChange handler exposes a bunch of values from it

1. currentValue
2. dataObject
3. syntheticEvent
4. formattedData

   <PhoneInput
   countryCodeEditable={false}
   country="in"
   disabled={disabled}
   enableSearch
   disableSearchIcon
   searchPlaceholder="Search"
   onChange={(value, data, event) => onChange(event)}
   placeholder={placeholder}
   inputProps={{
   required,
   autoFocus: false,
   ref,
   name,
   }}
   />

and it will just work like this.